# assign a new col to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function who gets a dataframe and calculate a value according to each sell in the table and returns a list.
I used the below code to assign a new column in my table using the output of my function:

```
df.assign(Points = pd.Series(calculate_point(df), index=df.index))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I have no idea what would be the problem. Can you please help me figure that out?

Thanks
Hany

Comment: `.assign` returns a *new dataframe* and does not work in-place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas dataframe assign doesn't update the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052676/pandas-dataframe-assign-doesnt-update-the-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df['Points'] = pd.Series(calculate_point(df), index=df.index)
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

What i do, is assign columns like this:

```
df['newColumnName'] = pd.Series(calculate_point(df), index=df.index)
```

If you want **efficiency**, use this other:

```
df.loc[:,'newColumnName'] = pd.Series(calculate_point(df), index=df.index)
```